# Why are bones not returning to the location set in each saved Pose?

Tags: bones, library

I have set up an armature with 9 bones, all 9 are aligned and stored as the Rest position, then each named bone is stored in the Armature's Object Data Properties "Pose Library" with a transform of 1.0 on the X axis.

[image: W Library Pose]

Im not using any deforms or IKs, just a position change from 0.0 to 1.0 on the X axis,

The issue is if i choose a different pose, for example E, the expectation is that the previous bone (WR) should return to 0.0 on the X axis, but instead seems stuck at its old pose position

[image: should only show "E Pose"]

Im not sure how to fix this and google has been no help.

Also for my eventual intentions, i will be using bones x location as a driver for activating shape keys together with rhubarb lip sync. Here is the tutorial I followed:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZVtUEEssxQ&t=165s

BLEND FILE https://pasteall.org/blend/ab5800af637c4b819ea4cb8e64a1f81e

Comment: for example for the bottom bone called FV, it looks like you didn't select it when you saved the poses, therefore when you call one of these poses, FV will stay where it has been deplaced in the previous poses (for example if you've called FV, FV will first move, then when you'll call the pose called M, the FV bone will stay where it has been moved as you haven't assigned any pose for the bone FV for the pose called M)

Comment: @moonboots: can i somehow see which bones/infos are saved in a pose?

Comment: @Chris, I don't think so, it would make sense to have a button that select the bones that have been saved for a given pose

Comment: yes it would!!!

Comment: and i think your answer is totally right ;)

Comment: I'll give it another shot tomorrow, but I repeated the posing process at least 7 times ensuring that i selected all bones, even made sure that all of the unused bones were at 0.0. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure of 2 things, whether you want to save or call the pose in the *Pose Library*, you need to select all the bones, otherwise the bone may not be saved or called at the position you expect.

Comment: Thank you and Yes i selected all the bones to save for each pose, with the 1 bone set at 1.0 x axis, all others at 0.0. per pose, I did manage to find a workaround by setting the 0.0 bones to -0.1 and this got it working. Just weird that it did not work as intended

Comment: maybe share your file so that we can test? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Link is now in the post